# Warning of incompatible version when connecting to older version of SQL Server R Services from a client using SQL Server vNext CTP 1.0

Tags: sql-server, r, sql-server-2016

I receive the following error when running an R command for SQL in Visual Studio:

*You are running version 9.0.1 of Microsoft R client on your computer, which is incompatible with the Microsoft R server version 8.0.3. Download and install a compatible version.*

This page - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt590540.aspx indicates:

*To fix this issue, you can use sqlbindr.exe in the R Server 9.0 release to upgrade your SQL Server instance to the compatible 9.0 version. A servicing fix for SQL RTM CU3+ and SP1+ versions will be released in the near future.*

I managed to find sqlbindr.exe by downloading the latest version of R server from Microsoft. Running this utility on my SQL Server does not seem to do anything. There may be some arguments needed.

I have SQL Server 2016 SP1 installed. I am able to execute the "Hello World" type example through TSQL.

Any ideas?

Edit: Through some trial and error I found that on the server running SQLBindR.exe with /list will show the instances of SQL presumably bound to R. SQLBindR.exe /bind  seems like what I would need. But I get the message. "The instance must have a compatible version of SQL R Services (in-DB) installed. See  for more details. "

So it seems like my SQL R Services is perhaps not updated correctly. I thought this would install via SQL Server SP1 and prior to that the installer.

*Fixed* (ish)

There seems to be some incompatibility between R Client 9.01 and SQL Server R Services although the compatibility chart indicates otherwise.

I found this very helpful post (http://www.desertislesql.com/wordpress1/?p=1340) that set me down the right path to figuring out the issue. Testing with a local context got rid of the error. I downloaded an older version of R Client from this Visual Studio Dev Essentials and that one worked.

I feel like based on the documentation the latest R Client should work, but I am not sure if there is a problem with my particular setup or the compatibility. Not sure yet what other issues there are with the old version of R Client, but at least it works now.

Comment: Did you try turning it off and back on again (meaning restart the service)?

Comment: Yes, several times. Not exactly my first rodeo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to install [GDR update package for SQL Server 2016 SP1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3210089) which contains [FIX: Version of R Client is incompatible with the Microsoft R server version 8.0.3](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3210262).  This was released without much fanfare on 12/16/2016.

I haven't tried this myself but I ran across a reference to the SQL 2016 SP1 GDR update today when reading other R Services MSDN docs.

Comment: Worked perfectly Bob. Thank you very much!

Comment: For information on the patch applicable to specific SQL Server version, please refer to the KB article on this topic: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3210262